# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.data' has no attribute 'experimental'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to run the image segmentation tutorial from tensorflow.

i am getting this error in the line

`from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix`

The comeplete error is following

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-bfebd9cf4be1> in <module>()
----> 1 from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
      2 
      3 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
      4 tfds.disable_progress_bar()
      5 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_examples\models\pix2pix\pix2pix.py in <module>()
     37 IMG_WIDTH = 256
     38 IMG_HEIGHT = 256
---> 39 AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
     40 
     41 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.data' has no attribute 'experimental'
```

Comment: What's your Tensorflow version (`import tensorflow as tf`, then `tf.__version__`)?

Comment: @ desertnaut it is 1.10.0

Comment: @desertnaut the tensorflow version is 1.10.0

Comment: You'll need TF 2.x to run this

Comment: @desertnaut okay i am installing it now. Will let you know when it works. Thank you!